# If $abc=1$ and $\prod_{\text{cyc}}(a^2+b^2)=8$, then $(a+b+c)^3\prod_{\text{cyc}}(a^2+b^2)\ge\left (\sum_{\operatorname{cyc}} (a^2b+b^2a) \right) ^3$.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0 $ where $abc=1$ and $(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)=8$.  Prove that $$ (a+b+c)^3(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2) \ge \big((a^2b+b^2a)(b^2c+c^2b)(c^2a+a^2c)\big) ^3.$$

Thanks

Comment: What does $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc}$ mean? And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: $$\sum_{\operatorname{cyc}} (a^2b+b^2a)=a^2b+b^2a+b^2c+c^2b+c^2a+a^2c$$

Comment: why have you in you exercise $(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)$ as long as you know that product is $8$? you can simplify your inequality!

Comment: you can use this methods: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=541062

Comment: If we simplify it, I think that it becomes more difficult. That's why I've homogenized it.

Comment: @math110, I tried before but It didn't work.

Comment: Source?${}{}{}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson , Unknown

Comment: ??? You don't know where you found this problem?

Comment: From a friend .

Comment: @Arthur, I think that $\sum\limits_{cyc} a+b = (a+b) + (b+c) + (c+a)$

Comment: @Juris I assumed so too, but my point is that that is the kind of things I should not _have_ to ask about. For Gogola: I've fixed my answer, by the way. At least I think so.

Comment: Come on, sport --- where did your friend find this problem? Some ongoing contest? a take-home final?

Comment: You can just expand everything and Muirhead it.

Answer (score 2):

**New proof**

I would like to start by looking at the second limitation, $(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)=8$. Multiplying the parentheses and noting that $abc = 1$ gives $a^4b^2 = \frac{a^4b^2c^2}{c^2} = \frac{a^2}{c^2}$, we get
\begin{align}
8 &= (a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\\\\
8 &= a^4 b^2+a^4 c^2+a^2 b^4+a^2 c^4+b^4 c^2+b^2 c^4+2a^2b^2c^2\\\\
9 &=  \frac{b^2 + c^2}{a^2}+\frac{a^2 + c^2}{b^2}+\frac{a^2 + b^2}{c^2} + 3\\\\
9 &=  \frac{b^2 + c^2}{a^2}+\frac{a^2 + c^2}{b^2}+\frac{a^2 + b^2}{c^2} +\frac{a^2}{a^2}+\frac{b^2}{b^2}+\frac{c^2}{c^2}\\\\
9 &= (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) \bigg( \frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\bigg)
\end{align}
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality this means that the vectors $(a, b, c)$ and $(\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b}, \frac{1}{c})$ are linearly dependant, which again means that $a^2 = b^2 = c^2$, and thus $a=b=c = 1$. Now the original inequality shouldn't be too hard to prove.

Comment: (+1) I've checked your revised proof, and it looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM, $\left(a^2+b^2\right)\geq 2ab$ and similarly for two other pairs.  Hence, $$8=\prod_{\text{cyc}}\,\left(a^2+b^2\right) \geq \prod_{\text{cyc}}\,(2ab)=8\,(abc)^2=8\,.$$
Therefore, the equality holds, implying that $a=b=c=1$.